# Selecting records with max version

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table as follows:

```
ConfigID | VersionNo | ObjectType
```

ConfigID and VersionNo constitute the unique key.
I want to be able to select the record with the highest VersionNo for each configID based on an object type.

I have tried

```
configs = (from config in configRepository.FindBy(x => x.ObjectType.Equals(typeof(Node).ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
           group config by config.ConfigID into orderedConfigs
           select orderedConfigs.OrderBy(x => x.ConfigID).ThenByDescending(x => x.VersionNo).First());
```

EDIT: I must add that the FindBy is basically just a where clause.
But I am getting no results. Please help me with this.

EDIT:

The data in the table could look like:

```
3fa1e32a-e341-46fd-885d-8f06ad0caf2e | 1 | Sybrin10.Common.DTO.Node
3fa1e32a-e341-46fd-885d-8f06ad0caf2e | 2 | Sybrin10.Common.DTO.Node
51d2a6c7-292d-42fc-ae64-acd238d26ccf | 3 | Sybrin10.Common.DTO.Node
51d2a6c7-292d-42fc-ae64-acd238d26ccf | 4 | Sybrin10.Common.DTO.Node
8dbf7a33-441f-40bc-b594-e34c5a2c3f51 | 1 | Some Other Type
91413e73-4997-4643-b7d2-e4c208163c0d | 1 | Some Other Type
```

From this I would only want to retrieve the second and fourth records as they have the highest version numbers for the configID and are of the required type.

Comment: can you show me an example with some of data ?

Comment: you are grouping by ConfigID twice, look at my answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if 100% works because writing out of VS :) but idea should be good

```
var configs = configRepository.Where(x=>x.ObjectType==typeof(Node).ToString());

var grouped = configs.GroupBy(x=>x.ConfigId);

var a = grouped.select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.VersionNo).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks LINQ sql to but in pure SQL i can write the query like this

> SELECT ConfigID ,MAX(VersionNo ) FROM CUSTOMIZE_COLUMNS_DETAIL WHERE
>   ObjectType = 'objectType' GROUP BY ConfigID

I have tried to replicate the scenario in sql , might by useful to you, THanks

Comment: We're using OpenAccess to talk to our DBs so SQL won't help here. Thanks for the answer though.